# Sorting objective-C array: where does 'element' come from?

Tags: objective-c

I'm reading a book on Objective-C. A part dealing with sorting arrays in an Addressbook. The sort method is like this:

```
- (void) sort
{
[book sortUsingSelector: @selector(compareNames:);
}
```

The 'compareNames' method is like this:

```
//Compare the two names from the specified address cards
-(NSComparisonResult) compareNames: (id) element
{
return [name compare: [element name]];
}
```

I kinda can see how it works. By comparing each element of the array to the next until all the 'names' are swapped in alphabetical order.

What I don't get (as it hasn't been mentioned earlier) is where the '(id) element' argument comes from? The 'name' I get cause that's been initialized earlier. But where does 'element' come from? Is that a fixed object that comes with NSArray? Earlier is described how to print an element by e.g. NSLogging nummer[1]. In case of this address book one element or card in that book could be printed by NSLogging book[32]. But how does 'element' fit in that?

Comment: it appears that `sortUsingSelector` will iterate through your array, therefore element will be the current element

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The 'name' I get cause that's been initialized earlier.

I'm not sure you understand how this works. The method corresponding to the sorting selector must compare **two objects that are members of the array.** No "static" objects, no ahead-of-time-initialized stuff, nothing.

This method will be called **on an object in the array,** and its argument will be **another object in the array,** to which it should compare the first object (its `self` argument). The implementation of `sortUsingSelector:` uses the return value of this method to decide if two objects are in the right order. Internally, it is called like this:

```
id oneObject = array[firstIndex];
id otherObject = array[secondIndex];

NSComparisonResult cmpRes =
    [oneObject performSelector:@selector(comparisonSelector)
                    withObject:otherObject];

if (cmpRes == NSOrderedDescending) {
    // swap the objects if they're in the wrong order
}
```

Maybe the asymmetry is confusing; in principle, `NSArray` could as well use a freestanding function that takes two objects and returns the comparison result. Actually, there indeed is a method (`sortUsingComparator:`) that takes a block which isn't called "on an object" (since it's not a method), but it's simply called with two arguments: the two objects to compare.

Comment: Yes, that part I get. I know it's comparing two objects in the array and compares the 'name' part in each object or element of that array. What I don't get is where '(id) element' comes from. Is that a preset name for any array element in the objective-c language? Or could I just as well use '(id) thiscard'?

Comment: @jiggy1965 Well, that's just the argument of the method. You can name your method arguments however you want. It could as well have been called `cutePinkyUnicorn`. (BTW, you should be comparing `self.name` to `element.name`.)

Answer (score 0):

It's pretty simple. The sorting algorithm is based on object-comparison. Let's say we have 3 objects in the array: `[A, B, C]`.

Then the method `compareNames:` is called on the following objects:

`[A compareNames:B]`
`[B compareNames:C]`
`[A compareNames:C]`

The `element` is just some other object in the array.